# Why won't kubernetes v1.5 recognize service.spec.loadBalancerIp?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running kubernetes v1.5 (api reference [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.5/#service-v1)). The field `service.spec.loadBalancerIp` should exist but I keep getting the following error when I attempt to set it.

`error: error validating ".../service.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field loadBalancerIp for v1.ServiceSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

service.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIp: xx.xx.xx.xx
  selector:
    deployment: some-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

kubectl version output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:53:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:34:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm running my cluster on gke.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your spec. It should be `loadBalancerIP`, not `loadBalancerIp`. Note the uppercase `P`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a ton.